# Incorrect permissions on special files

Tags: linux, files, filesystems, proc

I've noticed a lot of special files on Linux have what appears to be incorrect permissions:

E.g.:

```
$ ls -l /dev/fuse 
  crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 10, 229 May 29 09:59 /dev/fuse
```

appears writable but in fact isn't

```
$ echo 1 > /dev/fuse
  -bash: echo: write error: Operation not permitted
```

Same e.g., for all files in `/proc/$pid/attr`:

```
$ ls -l /proc/1/attr/
total 0
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 May 30 11:01 current
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 May 30 11:01 exec
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 May 30 13:31 fscreate
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 May 30 11:01 keycreate
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 May 30 11:01 prev
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 May 30 11:01 sockcreate
$ echo 1 >| /proc/1/attr/keycreate 
-bash: echo: write error: Permission denied
```

Is this a bug?
(BTW, I have no idea what these files do).

Comment: never "> file" if you don't know what file is for (or how it is used)... you could clear it / mess it up beyond repair ...

Comment: @OlivierDulac But I need to find out what all the big red don-press-me buttons do. :D

Comment: The permission is right this file. But dont expect it will do what you are expecting for. /proc is like a lot of memory files or variables related to the kernel. For example some parts need to be used for all processes on the system must have a+rw permissions, but dont expect it will have something related to system security, so no, you will not able to do anything with it.

Comment: /dev/fuse is used for : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace . For example if you use "sshfs", or something like this. When not in use, it will lead to nothing (the permissions are right, but it is not currently pointing/leading to anything). When in use, it could lead to a viable filesystem, which you could mess up or even destroy if you ">" into it ... [ymmv] . And /proc/1 is for "init" , which you don't want to mess with. (And there are many others you don't want to mess with ... ^^)

Comment: I'd replace all the "never" with "unless you are prepared to accept complete annihilation"... learning stuff the hard way is something fun you should not take away from someone by saying never. :)

Comment: @OlivierDulac I don't know what attr/keycreate is supposed to do in particular, but I figured both /dev/fuse and /proc/1 (i know it's init) are important and Linux wouldn't let me mess with important stuff if I wasn't root. I wouln't try this on a regular process's /proc because I care about not messing up my regular processes. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think my 2 comments could be an answer...

1) never "> file" if you don't know what file is for (or how it is used)... you could clear it / mess it up beyond repair ...

2) for your 2 particular examples:

- /dev/fuse is used for : en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace . For example if you use "sshfs", or something like this. When not in use, it will lead to nothing (the permissions are right, but it is not currently pointing/leading to anything). When in use, it could lead to a viable filesystem, which you could mess up or even destroy if you ">" into it ... [ymmv]
- And /proc/1 is for "init" , which you don't want to mess with.

(And there are many others you don't want to mess with ... ^^)

Answer (score 1):

These are not simply files like on ext4 and other familiar filesystems...

```
# mount | grep -E "on /proc |on /dev "
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
dev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,...)
```

In the case of /proc, you have a virtual filesystem, procfs, that represents stuff going on in the kernel, and these things are sorta not really files at all, but a file based interface into the kernel. They are backed by some driver that has a job other than just organizing bytes of data and metadata. On such "virtual filesystems", there can be special behavior that seems to defy your normal understanding of filesystems.

For example this may look weird:

```
# echo hi > /proc/testfile
-bash: /proc/testfile: No such file or directory
```

In the case of /dev, which is a tmpfs, devtmpfs (on Arch without systemd for example), or devfs (FreeBSD for example), and maybe something else with systemd, things behave like on a normal filesystem (or potentially not), but it generally has "special files" instead of regular files. You could possibly copy these to another filesystem or make your own (eg. with mknod, or mkfifo) to see how they behave differently. With a special file "echo hi > somefile" might not mean "open the file, truncate it, and write hi" but to forward the "hi" to some driver or something else.

```
# file /dev/sda /dev/mem /dev/fuse /dev/null
/dev/sda:  block special (8/0)
/dev/mem:  character special (1/1)
/dev/fuse: character special (10/229)
/dev/null: character special (1/3)

# file -s /dev/sda /dev/mem /dev/fuse /dev/null
/dev/sda:  DOS/MBR boot sector, extended partition table (last)
/dev/mem:  ERROR: cannot read `/dev/mem' (Operation not permitted)
/dev/fuse: ERROR: cannot read `/dev/fuse' (Operation not permitted)
/dev/null: empty
```

But copying them with cp doesn't (always?) work. (I forget how to do this, or possibly imagined it)

```
# cp /dev/null /tmp
# file -s /tmp/null
/tmp/null: empty
# echo hi > /tmp/null
# file -s /tmp/null
/tmp/null: ASCII text

# cp /dev/sda /tmp/
... it is copying the whole disk to /tmp now ... hit ctrl+c
```

Comment: the last part is a bit confused (or at least confusing) : "/dev" isn't (too) special in itself (apart from its name/path itself, which is where lots of specials files are supposed to be), but the file type inside are special. They often are Block or Caracter files, with a specific Major & Minor number indicating to the kernel what they do/where they point to. See:  `ls -l /dev/null`. You could create similar files anywhere: `mknod /tmp/anothernull c 1 3` ... (note: /dev/null is needed as is, don't delete it or you'll experience lots of painful things [and rebooting may even prove difficult])

Comment: @OliverDulac I think I already said that. "like a normal filesystem...but...has special files". To clarify it, which words would you change and into what?